# Does working in a alcohol store and selling alcohol and other Stuff breaks your fast

Tags: halal-haram, sunnah

I work in a store and I sell Alcohol,THC etc is my fasting valid?

Answer (score 0):

Selling alcohol is haram.

> لعن الله الخمر وشاربها وساقيها وبائعها ومبتاعها وعاصرها ومعتصرها وحاملها والمحمولة إلي
>
> Allah has cursed wine, its drinker, its server, its seller, its buyer, its presser, the one for whom it is pressed, the one who conveys it, and the one to whom it is conveyed.
>
> <sup>— [Abu Dawud](https://sunnah.com/abudawud:3674)</sup>

> إن الله ورسوله حرم بيع الخمر
>
> Allah and His Messenger made illegal the trade of alcohol
>
> <sup>— [Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:2236)</sup>

And it is even more blameworthy to continue doing haram during Ramadan:

> من لم يدع قول الزور والعمل به فليس لله حاجة في أن يدع طعامه وشرابه
>
> Whoever does not give up forged speech and evil actions, Allah is not in need of his leaving his food and drink.
>
> <sup>— [Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:1903)</sup>

> رب صائم ليس له من صيامه إلا الجوع. ورب قائم ليس له من قيامه إلا السهر
>
> There are people who fast and get nothing from their fast except hunger, and there are those who pray and get nothing from their prayer but a sleepless night.
>
> <sup>— [Ibn Majah](https://sunnah.com/ibnmajah:1690)</sup>

However it will not break your fast. A fast is broken voluntarily mainly by doing that which is specifically forbidden in fasting such as intentionally eating, drinking, ejaculating or ending the intention of fasting - during the period from dawn to sunset.